# Load entire folder of Java Configuration files?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-annotations

Is there any way to load a entire folder with @Configuration files, the same way XML have: `<import resource="folder/*.xml" />`, but with annotations?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use component scanning.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example.configs")
public class Config {
}
```

All @Configuration classes from the `org.example.configs` package will be included in the context.

Typesafe alternative:

```
// org.example.configs.SubConfig
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SubConfig.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

The pendant of `<import resource="folder/*.xml" />` but using configuration is [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)

For example:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("folder/*.xml")
public class MyConfiguration {}
```